# GIS DATA conversion

Tags: gis, semantics

i am looking for tool make me convert ESRI shapefile to RDF files 
and this tool can include in
Web Server build in C#

Comment: I suggest asking this at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by Shapefile to RDF, but you can use the open source tool [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html) to convert between most spatial formats, and Mapserver's [mapscript](https://mapserver.org/mapscript/mapscript.html) to create a GIS based web server in c#.